# All browsers work in different ways in determining the positions

Tags: cross-browser

Hi i have the big problem is that all browsers positioning differently.
Each template in the center of the other shows do not represent correctly.
Say When a person opens the site instead of the template.
One side shows less over another.
I did some work at my computer it all works in all browsers.
I do not understand what I was doing wrong the first time for me after all this is so.
I tried the other browsers and fonts and change the screen size.
Does not fix the problem.

Why is this happening for all browsers ?
Also tried to use position: absolute, but nothing works, too.
Maybe you can look at my website and see what you see it correctly or in bad what I am doing wrong and why it works for me correctly using a different position: absolute or relative or all browsers ?
just on the other computers browsers do not show correctly positions

Here is my code can you fix it cuz i didn't understand what where to create div container inside wrap or where ?

```
html,body{
background-color: #181818;
color: #fff;
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: auto;
}

*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.wrap{
 position:absolute; bottom: -1px; top: 10px;
 margin-left: 4%; *margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 4%; *margin-right: 5%;
}

.time{
color: #fff;
font-size: 8pt;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute; top: -2px; left: 943px; width: 150px;
position:absolute; *top: 3px; *left: 930px; width: 150px;
}

.top{
  width: 1024px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: #444;
  background:transparent url('top.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius-topright: 10px;    
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius-topleft: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  }


.header{
  width: 1044px;
  *width: 1024px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #333;
  position:relative;  bottom: 10px;
  background:transparent url('head.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x;
 }

.menu{
  width: 1024px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #474747;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position:relative;  bottom: 11px;
  background:transparent url('menu.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

 .list {
position:absolute; left: 20px; top: 1px;
}


.content{
  width: 1024px;
  height: 1200px;
  background: #000;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: #111;
  position:relative;  bottom: 10px;
  }

.aprasymas{
  position:absolute; top: 10px; width: 350px;
 }

 .forma{
  position:absolute; top: -3px; left: 720px;
  position:absolute; *top: 1px; *left: 700px;
  background:transparent url('forma.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 312px; height: 157px;
 }

.imgbox{
 position:absolute; top: 10px;

 }

.photo{
 position:absolute; top: 150px; left: 590px; width: 441px; height:141 *top: 60px; *left: 570px;
 background:transparent url('photo.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.photo2{
 position:absolute; top: 280px; left: 590px; width: 441px; height:141 *top: 60px; *left: 570px;
 background:transparent url('photo.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat 
}

.photo3{
 position:absolute; top: 410px; left: 590px; width: 441px; height:141 *top: 60px; *left: 570px;
 background:transparent url('photo.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.phototekstas{
 position:relative; top: -15px; left: 90px; width: 300px;
 position:relative; *top: -16px; *left: 85px; *width: 380px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-size: *8pt;
 padding: 3em;
}



.footer{
  width: 1024px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #333;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position:relative;  bottom: 10px;
  background:transparent url('footer.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;  
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.copyright{
 color: #aaa;
 position:absolute; width: 310px; left: 835px; bottom: 12px;
 position:absolute; width: 310px; *left: 820px; *bottom: 13px;
 font-size: 8pt;
 }

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 .copyright {
position:absolute; width: 310px; left: 810px; bottom: 12px;
 }
 }

 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
 .phototekstas {
position:relative; top: -18px; left: 90px; width: 300px;
 }
 }

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 .time {
position:absolute; top: 1px; left: 945px; width: 150px;
 }
 }

 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
 .forma {
position:absolute; top: 1px; left: 720px;
 }
 }

/* will be red only in google chrome */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .time{position:absolute; top: 3px; left: 950px; width: 150px;}
}

/* Opera */
@media not screen and (1) {
.time {
position:absolute; top: -2px; left: 950px; width: 150px;
} /* OP 11 */
}
```

This is the main what i'm positioning all template without hard work.

```
.wrap{
 position:absolute; bottom: -1px; top: 10px;
 margin-left: 4%; *margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 4%; *margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Here's my link: http://mrblackscripts.3owl.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a relatively-positioned "container" div, then set absolutely positioned objects inside of that div.

That will absolutely position the elements on the page. However, it is probably not best-practice.

Comment: For example: <div id="container" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;"><div id="content" style="position:absolute;margin-left:10px;margin-top:15px;"></div></div>

Comment: I fixed chrome,firefox and opera but now i have the problem with ie9

Comment: The man head floated to the left corner. I useed this code to fix the body to center all my web template and it works but not in ie9 cuz i'm on windows 7 the this is a good news to know that almost i fixed myselft it just left only the ie9 how to fix ? Thanks. here the code i used for the body and it works width: 1024px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

Comment: Put the logo inside of a div in the body and the give the logo a negative margin left (if i understand you correctly)

Comment: I refixed all my code and cleared it to work correctly but no html5 doctype or other even position do not work correctly too. This too shtml5 is not working it messed my not all code design. I do not know i saw many question about position problem on ie 9 in all browsers work correct but i do not know how to fix for other computers it expand all windows and do not show template positions as has to be you look at this now why this happening i saw many websites who has the problem as me but the do not care that.

Comment: The ie is always ruins all my plans and i'm beginner i do not how to fix it.